# Redirect to external non-Wicket page in Wicket 1.5

Tags: wicket

How do I do the following in Wicket 1.5?

```
page.getRequestCycle().setRequestTarget(new RedirectRequestTarget("http://www.facebook.com/login.php?api_key="+ _apiKey + "&v=1.0"));
```

I want to do a Facebook application using Wicket 1.5, and I want at some point to redirect the user to the Facebook login page. A lot has changed as highlighted in *[Migrating to Wicket 1.5](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/migration-to-wicket-15.html)*.

Answer (score 9):

Using HTTP 302 ("Moved Temporarily"):

```java
import org.apache.wicket.request.flow.RedirectToUrlException;
...
throw new RedirectToUrlException(
    "http://www.facebook.com/login.php?api_key="+ _apiKey + "&v=1.0");
```

Using HTTP 301 ("Moved Permanently", SEO friendly):

```java
import org.apache.wicket.request.flow.RedirectToUrlException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
...
throw new RedirectToUrlException(
    "http://www.facebook.com/login.php?api_key="+ _apiKey + "&v=1.0", 
    HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
```

Answer (score 5):

See
`org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.scheduleRequestHandlerAfterCurrent(IRequestHandler)`
and
`org.apache.wicket.request.http.handler.RedirectRequestHandler.RedirectRequestHandler(String)`

Comment: thanks Martin-g. this bit worked but I had to go back to wicket 1.4.17 cz I want to get this app working asap the I will migrate to 1.5 fully!